# Maven Nested Multi-module project

Tags: maven, nested, multi-module

I am building a multi-module project where one of the modules is also a multi-module project. When I try to build the nested multi-module independently using `-pl <multi-module child>`, Maven only builds the pom(the top-level module of the child) and does not build the rest of the modules specified in the multi-module project.

If I don't use the `-pl` and build all the modules, everything work fine, the project builds as intended.

Any ideas why this might be happening, I can't get Maven to build the entire project if I single it out individually?

Answer (score 3):

The `-pl` option builds exactly the projects that you specify. Maven treats a parent POM as a regular project that happens to be the first in the hierarchy.
What you can do is browse into your "sub-multimodule" project and execute Maven from there. The option `-rf` (resume from) might also work.

Comment: I can't browse to the module because I am executing a build from the top level parent and specifying which project I need built. So, now I have to build all 12 of them in order to build this muli-module project when I only want to build 2. I tried "mvn clean deploy -pl <child-multi-module> -rf <child-muliti-module> and no luck. Same result as before, only the pom is built.

Comment: could you try it without -pl ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way to achieve that is to use `-pl` to refer to one of the grandchild submodules. As it probably depends on its siblings, will can possibly achieve the same result.

This project is a great example on how to do that:
https://github.com/andyglick/maven-multi-level-modules-project

In short, you can do:

```
mvn test -pl com.example:my-grandchild-module -am
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason for Maven behaving that way, other than this is how Maven always behaved for `-pm`. The `-am` option could include the modules listed of any module listed in `-pl`, because the parent "depends on them" in a way, but because they are not dependencies in the strict sense, Maven does not.

If Maven were an active project, a new `-amm` also-make-modules option might help.